# Disable interaction of UWP app with the Tab Key

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am building a UWP app. I want that my app does not respond to the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key at all. I mean that my app should completely ignore whenever the user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the `PreviewKeyDown` event of your page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.PreviewKeyDown += MainPage_PreviewKeyDown;
}

private void MainPage_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

However, I would advise against that, because this removes an important part of the accessibility of your app - many users like to or need to use keyboard to navigate.

### Application-wide solution

If you want to handle the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key application-wide, you can do that in two ways:

#### Create a custom base page type

You can create a new class like `PageBase` which will derive from `Page` and will have the `PreviewKeyDown` event handling set up in its constructor. All other pages you will have in your app can then derive from `PageBase`.

#### Handling <kbd>Tab</kbd> on root `Frame`

You can add `PreviewKeyDown` handler to the app's root `Frame` control in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.PreviewKeyDown += RootFrame_PreviewKeyDown;
```

Comment: Can this be achieved at the app level?

Comment: How could I disable (temporarily) key like: win key, ctr+alt+delete, alt+F4?

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually possible, as these are system-wide shortcuts, unfortunately